# getting a 401 error on connecting to linkedin rest api with volley

Tags: android-volley, linkedin-api

I am trying to get email address of a user through linkedin's rest api. I am using volley for the request. But it shows 401 error. Can anyone help me through this. Below is the code. Access token is for r_basicprofile and r_emailaddress permissions

```
private static final String PROFILE_URL = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address)";
private static final String OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_PARAM ="oauth2_access_token";
private static final String QUESTION_MARK = "?";
private static final String EQUALS = "=";
private static final String HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type";
private static final String HEADER_AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";
private static final String HEADER_SRC = "x-li-src";
private static final String HEADER_LI_FORMAT = "x-li-format";
private static final String HEADER_LI_VER = "x-li-msdk-ver";
private static final String CONTENT_VALUE = "application/json";
private static final String HEADER_SRC_VALUE = "msdk";
private static final String HEADER_LI_FORMAT_VALUE = "json";

private TextView welcomeText;
private ProgressDialog pd;
String accessToken;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fflifind_friends);
    welcomeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_profile_welcome_text);

    //Request basic profile of the user
    SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("user_info", 0);
    accessToken = preferences.getString("accessToken", null);
    if(accessToken!=null){
        String profileUrl = getProfileUrl(accessToken);
        Log.d("profile url", profileUrl);
       // new GetProfileRequestAsyncTask().execute(profileUrl);
        doServer(profileUrl);
    }
}

private Map<String, String> getLiHeaders(String accessToken) {
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put(HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_VALUE);
    headers.put(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + accessToken);
    headers.put(HEADER_SRC, HEADER_SRC_VALUE);
    headers.put(HEADER_LI_FORMAT, HEADER_LI_FORMAT_VALUE);
    //headers.put(HEADER_LI_VER, BuildConfig.MSDK_VERSION);
    return headers;
}
private static final String getProfileUrl(String accessToken){
    String url = PROFILE_URL
                + QUESTION_MARK
                + OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_PARAM + EQUALS + accessToken;
        return url;

}

public void doServer(String url)
{
    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, null, "Loading data ");
    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Log.d("Jsonres-", response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("error ","err");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            return getLiHeaders(accessToken);
        }
    };
    NetworkRequestQueue.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to get the profile information of linkedin account and define what you want from profile in **PROFILE_LINK** string mention below it's working fine for me.I hope its solved your problem.

```
     public static final String HOST="https://api.linkedin.com/";
        public static final String PROFILE_LINK=HOST+"v1/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,picture-url)?oauth2_access_token=";
        public static final String JSON_FORMAT=AMPERSAND+"format=json";

 private void profileRequestAsyncTask(final String accessToken) {

        showProgressDialog();
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity);

        String url=PROFILE_LINK+accessToken+JSON_FORMAT;
        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: "+response );
                        JSONObject dataAsJson= null;
                        try {
                            dataAsJson = new JSONObject(response);
                            String id=dataAsJson.getString("id");
                            String firstName=dataAsJson.getString("firstName");
                            String lastName=dataAsJson.getString("lastName");
                            String pictureUrl=dataAsJson.getString("pictureUrl");

                            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: "+id+"="+firstName+"-"+lastName+"-"+pictureUrl );
                            String username=firstName+" "+lastName;
                            insertLinkedinAccount(id,username,pictureUrl,accessToken,expires);


                            editor.clear();
                            editor.commit();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        //Log.e(TAG, "onApiSuccess:profileData- "+firstName+"-"+lastName+"-"+profileId);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponse: "+error );
            }
        });

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);


    }
```